# How do I make AVAudioSession work in silent mode and with .mixWithOthers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioengine, avaudiosessioncategory

I'm writing an iOS app in Swift (Xcode 11.5) using AVAudioEngine

It's all working fine, but I can't get it to play along with other audio apps when the iPhone/iPad has the mute button off.

With this:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
```

my audio works with the mute button on or off, but if I'm playing something from Apple Music, when I hit play on my audio, Apple Music pauses.

With this:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.ambient, options: .mixWithOthers)
```

my audio works with Apple Music, but doesn't play if the mute button is off.

With this:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: [.mixWithOthers])
```

having .mixWithOthers makes no difference.

I'm sure there is a combination of options that will make it work with the mute button on or off and not stop other audio playing, but I can't find it!

TIA for any suggestions.

Ian

Comment: Mixing and ducking are your choices. They do work, though the details also depend on the other app.    You are not showing even enough code to prove that _you_ are doing this correctly.

Comment: Why has this been given a negative?  I've said nothing about the other app other than it's playing.

Comment: @matt I've figured this out and have answered the question - can't work out how to put a link to your name in the answer.  Thanks for your comment.  Ian

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out and, as pointed out by matt, I was doing something wrong! I can't post my code here because it is pretty big.  Basically, I've written and audio class that handles all the audio files, declares the engine, AVAudioEngine();  nodes, AVAudioPlayerNode(); and does all the playing and so on.

My mistake was to put this sort of stuff in that class, and it was obviously the wrong place:

```
do {
  let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
  try audioSession.setActive(false)
  if resetOptions.muteOtherApps {
    try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, options: [])
  } else {
    try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, options: [.mixWithOthers])
  }
} catch {
  print("Audio error")
}
```

Since  I'm letting the user choose between these options, it was convenient for me to put it in my main ViewController class.  However, if it's set fixed for the app, from what I've read a good place to put it is in AppDelegate.Swift in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function.
The main point, at least what worked for me, is to keep these things separate to the class that is actually managing the audio.

So, thanks Matt.

Ian

Comment: But this is not a very good answer. It still doesn’t contain enough code to explain how it solves the problem.

Comment: OK @matt - it will involve me writing a demo program, but I'll have a go at that over the w/e...

Comment: See, how do we know that code even ran, or when it ran in relation to your playing sound, or whether it ran again after an interruption? You’ve shown no context at all. The code by itself looks fine but without context it’s meaningless, just like the question.

Comment: @matt - so, I wrote a small program to try to demonstrate when it did and did not work and was unable to reproduce my original problem that was inside a large project.  So, I fully accept your comment that the question obviously didn't give sufficient context and that the problem was obviously with my code.  Not much more I can say really, other than that I'm pleased to have figured this stuff out... Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: hi. Can you explain what is "resetOptions" in your code ?

Comment: Hi @maryamchaharsooghi - sorry for the delay in getting back to you...
resetOptions is just a struct I have for the various setttings options in my program - I've actually renamed it 'settingsOptions'.  
You should think of resetOptions.muteOtherApps as a Bool that allows the user to select whether to mute other apps or not.
Hope that is clear.
Ian